# CSS to modify Firefox Chrome

Tags: css, firefox

I wish to modify Firefox 49.0.2 chrome running on macOS 10.10.5. I want to change the Bookmark pulldown.  I'm using stylist to update the css.

I browser chrome://browser/content/browser.xul which shows the chrome.  I can use Firefox inspector to see the css.  I've simplified what I want to do just to changing the color of "bookmark all tabs".

```
/* color [Bookmark all tabs] */
menuitem#menu_bookmarkAllTabs.show-only-for-keyboard{         
       color:yellowgreen!important;/**/}
```

This works for the pseudo chrome but not the real stuff.

[image]

I restarted Firefox,but I don't see a change.

[image]

I'm using a night shade thingie here, but earlier, I turned that off and the problem still persisted.

When I change the bookmark icon popup text, the real and pseudo chrome changes. No pictures of this.

```
/* Bookmark icon*/
/* color [Bookmarks toolbar]
   easer to find when looking for BMB_BookmarksShowAllTop */
menu#BMB_bookmarksToolbar {
  color:orange !important;
  }/**/
```

Comment: Probably a very stupid question, but the screenshot there is showing the menu bar of your desktop, right? That isn't part of Firefox's window?

Comment: That's a thought. The menu bar is display on the pseudo chrome.  Anyway, I want to change it.  I'm thinking the bar is displayed before Firefox knows I want to change it. Of course, the pseudo bar gets changed retroactively.